# How to print more than 256 array elements in Xcode lldb?

Tags: xcode, lldb

When I use `p` or `print` it will only print the first 256 elements.

How can I print all of them?

Comment: set set target.max-string-summary-length -1 worked for me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can tell lldb to force all the array elements to be printed for a particular expression evaluation thusly:

```
(lldb) expr -A -- array_variable
```

You can also raise the maximum number of elements (lldb calls them "children") that get printed by default by running:

```
(lldb) set set target.max-children-count 1024
```

or whatever value you want.  You can also put this in your `~/.lldbinit` if you want to up this limit for all your lldb sessions.