# Deque not growing larger than 255 elements

Tags: c++, xcode

Consider the following code:

```
#include <deque>

int main() {
    std::deque<int> a;

    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        a.push_back(i);
    }

    // Breakpoint in IDE
    // a contains only 255 elements ( [0] - [254] )

    return 0;
}
```

You would expect that a would contain 300 elements at the breakpoint (the numbers 0 to 299), but it doesn't. After the 255th element none are added, they are ignored. Why is this and how can I solve this.

I'm using XCode as my IDE, I don't know which compiler XCode uses, but I've probably set it to the default.

*I have tried to google it, because it seems to be a fairly easy problem, but couldn't find anything. Hopefully someone here can help me, I would be very grateful.*

**Edit:**
It's caused by Xcode not showing more than 255 elements in the GUI, haven't find a solution to that yet, but you can use lldb to show them all. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647198/how-to-print-more-than-256-array-elements-in-xcode-lldb).

Comment: Maybe the debugger simply does not display more than 250 elements? Did you try to print the size of `a`?

Comment: It displays 300, so I think that you are right. Is there a way I can make XCode also show the other elements?

Comment: @JXD i have the same problem in xcode 12, with queues of 500 (small) elements where only 255 are shown in the debugger. did you find out how to configure the xcode debugger to show the full contents of any object? btw, i have other objects (vectors) where all contents (10000+ elements, where each element itself is quite a big object) seems to be available to be inspected in the debugger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deque *will* have all 300 elements. It does not ignore elements after the 255<sup>th</sup>.

The debugger is probably just showing only up to a maximum limit, because the GUI would become unwieldy after that.

You can reconfigure your debugger, or debug your code in another way (such as by printing properties of the container, like `a.size()`).

Comment: LighnessRiO: same question to you as i posed to JXD above. i have the same problem in xcode 12, with queues of 500 (small) elements where only 255 are shown in the debugger. did you find out ***how to configure the xcode debugger*** to show the full contents of any object? btw, i have other objects (vectors) where all contents (10000+ elements, where each element itself is quite a big object) seems to be available to be inspected in the debugger.